Adding a new package broke my Spring Boot Application
I'm getting troubles since I have added a new package in my spring boot application containing Mapstructs' mappers. Looks like the field:
@Autowired    
private UtenteMapper utenteMapper; 

is not being populated in my Service component. The Spring boot main class, PaniECumpanagghiuApplicationConfiguration, is quite essential, (it contains only the @SpringBootApplicationAnnotation annotation), but I've tried previously to add a @ComponentScan.
@SpringBootApplication    
@ComponentScan("PaniECumpanagghiu.PaniECumpanagghiu.Mappers")

In this way the functionality is being recovered, but the @Controller is not fired (when I invoke my API the server retrieves 404). I tried also to add all the packages into the annotation @ComponentScan, like this
@ComponentScan("PaniECumpanagghiu.PaniECumpanagghiu.Mappers","PaniECumpanagghiu.PaniECumpanagghiu.controller",...)
In this way neither the former object, UtenteMapper, is populated anymore (same behavior than the case without @ComponentScan annotation).
If I comment all references to the new package, and I simplify the API in order to return only a String ("Ciao"), the controller is fired. This is my tree directory

I have described everything in the previous section.
EDIT 1
Hey guys i have the impression that the problem is in the mapstruct dependence importing.
So I decided to give you the whole pom.
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>PaniECumpanagghiu</groupId>
    <artifactId>PaniECumpanagghiu</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>PaniECumpanagghiu</name>
    <description>Web app di food delivery per la sicilia sud orientale</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.6.2</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>1.8</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>


Would be useful if I post other parts of the project in order to overcome to this?:( If you need something please let me know

You say "The Spring boot main class, PaniECumpanagghiuApplicationConfiguration" but in the screenshot you provided the main class is called PaniECumpanagghiuApplication

I don't remember if this is generated automatically by spring.initializer webapp, or if I renamed it...but this is the class containing @SpringBootApplication()

do you have a github repository for the project ?

It will be a commercial webapp, so I'd prefer to post code here...
The problem is mainly in the interation between Lombok and Mapstruct, which seems to get really in troubles together...

Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text. See [ask]. Don't post links to your github; links can break, linked content can change (especially on github!), making the question unanswerable and unusable for others with similar problems. Don't post your whole pom. Instead post a [mcve].

Why are you punishing my post? I need to post my whole pom because I need help on configuring it...I can't make Mapstruct and Lombok to work, and i need help to understand what I am doing wrong...
And I'm not giving to anyone my git account, but i surely need to post logs and code because I'm asking help in this site to make my webapp to work...

Because you are telling that perhaps the issue is connected to the interaction of Lombok and Mapstruct, perhaps (the pom.xml file says other annotation processors and I don't know if there are really others), you have to include both annotation processors in the maven-compiler-plugin, like this:
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </path>
        <path>
          <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
          <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
          <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </path>
      </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

Moreover: check if UtenteMapper is annotated with componentModel = "spring", like this:
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UtenteMapper {

Without that attribute set (read the javadoc) the generated mapper can't be managed as a Spring bean and won't be injected with @Autowired.
As a side note, just for conventions' sake: please use lower case starting packages, I suppose Eclipse is telling this already as a warning when creating classes and other packages.
